# How to deserialize JSON when the result returns different data type

Tags: json, flutter, dart, deserialization

I have an issue with my JSON result.

When my JSON response `is not empty` is returning a dictionary:

```
{
    "data": {},
    "errors": [],
    "memId": 0
}
```

When the JSON `is empty` is returning an empty array:

```
[ ]
```

How can I deal with this situation when I try to deserialize the JSON response ?

Here is my code:

```
factory MyJsonObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
  MyJsonObject(
    data: json["data"] == null ? null : Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
    errors: json["errors"] == null ? [] : List<dynamic>.from(json["errors"]!.map((x) => x)),
    memId: json["memId"],
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make param as `dynamic` and add type check:

```
factory MyJsonObject.fromJson(dynamic json) {
  if (json is Map<String, dynamic>) {
    return MyJsonObject(
      data: json["data"] == null ? null : Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
      errors: json["errors"] == null ? [] : 
      List<dynamic>.from(json["errors"]!.map((x) => x)),
      memId: json["memId"],
    );
  }
  return MyJsonObject.empty();
}
```

Comment: It should be return MyJsonObject in 3rd line

Comment: These type matches are better (and more concisely) done with the Dart 3 pattern matching.